# How to limit ng-options that come in through json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on a project where I need to allow people to choose the state as a choice from a drop down menu. I am pulling json from an API that has categories that I do not need but I cannot figure out how to omit them. My json looks sort of like this

```
categories: [
        {
          id: 1,
          slug: "a",
          title: "Alabama",
          parent: 234,
          post_count: 123

        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Alaska"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Arizona"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "Canada"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          title: "New York"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          title: "Mexico"
        },...
```

How do I sort out the data that is not a part of a US state (so get rid of Canada, Mexico, etc from the data with an ng-options? Right now it is showing a lot of content I do not want in the drop down list.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="x" ng-options="category.title for category in categories"
 ng-change="changedValue(x)">
</select>
```

Comment: Does your json contain the country? Without that or an array of states you are SOL

Comment: My Json has states and countries all under categories so it is making my dropdown list have countries and states all in the same list so I need to figure out how to only show the states

Comment: show me what alabama looks like..the full object

Comment: I edited it to show the full alabama

Comment: Hmm..yeah, see my first comment...unless `parent` points to united states or something.

Comment: Here is an example if your JSON had contained a country: https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/6/ You will utilize `filter`

Comment: What you could do is get a static array of states. Loop through `categories` and `indexOf` title vs array of states and inject a new property called `country` in the object where indexOf != -1

Comment: if parent: 234 equals united states could i use that?

Comment: Yes..anything that says, hey this is from the US...For example..if Alaska contains the same parent then you are fine..see my fiddle...change the filter to check for that parent value. If mexico contains the same parent value then you are not fine

Comment: so i should just use filter: 234?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a list of states in an array like this:

```
    var state = 
    [
    "Alabama",
    "Alaska",
    "American Samoa",
    "Arizona",
    "Arkansas",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware",
    "District Of Columbia",
    "Federated States Of Micronesia",
    "Florida",
    "Georgia",
    "Guam",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Illinois",
    "Indiana",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Kentucky",
    "Louisiana",
    "Maine",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Mississippi",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
    "Nebraska",
    "Nevada",
    "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey",
    "New Mexico",
    "New York",
    "North Carolina",
    "North Dakota",
    "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma",
    "Oregon",
    "Palau",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Puerto Rico",
    "Rhode Island",
    "South Carolina",
    "South Dakota",
    "Tennessee",
    "Texas",
    "Utah",
    "Vermont",
    "Virgin Islands",
    "Virginia",
    "Washington",
    "West Virginia",
    "Wisconsin",
    "Wyoming"
    ]
```

And when you got your options just filter to whatever exists in states array, something like this:

```
function filterByState(option) {
    return contains(states, option.title);
}

function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the usage:

```
var filteredOptions = categories.filter(filterByState);
```